# Intuitive explanation of trace minimization under constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the minimization problem bellow:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{V}{\text{min}}
& & \mbox{trace} (VAV^T) \\
& \text{s.t.} & &  VBV^T=I
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $V = [v_1, \dots, v_n]$ we may find the optimal $v_i$'s by solving the generalized eigenvalue problem ([look here](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/umsi-2009-31.pdf)):

$$AV=BV\Lambda$$

However, I can not understand how the constraint is fulfilled.

1. Could you please cast some light on this?
2. Is this optimization problem related with [simultaneous diagonalization](http://www.geo.tuwien.ac.at/downloads/tm/svd.pdf)?
3. Is the initial optimization problem and the one bellow equivalent? We perform first weightening in $B$, i.e., find $S$ such that $SBS^T=I$ and finally solve:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{V}{\text{min}}
& & \mbox{trace} (VSB^{1/2}A(B^{1/2})^{T}S^TV^T)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Thanks!

PS: $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices.

Comment: You can see that the constraint is satisfied by a whitening procedure, and it does have to do with simultaneous diagonalization, like you suspect. For details see the discussion here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/algebra/node7.html . However, it is unclear to me why the trace is minimized

Comment: I had this link on mind, for future task but I wan;t remembering the details, so as to make the connection. Thanks for you info!!

Comment: Are $\mathrm A, \mathrm B$ invertible?

Comment: Hello  @Rodrigo de Azevedo, mmm lets say that they are invertible:)